# Oracle SQL Window Optimization / Possible Oracle PL/SQL Solution?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I can't say how helpful this community has been! My usual problem has plagued me again. I have functional code that works great for lets say 1 week of data but does not have realistic runtimes for lets say... YTD data. (The table with the events is 3.5 billion rows, 10+ years) I'm using a window function to determine what happened on system events. I'm also using a case statement and 2 different fields to create a custom key to group the events (I wish the source data just had a key already).

I don't know PL/SQL well but I was thinking someone to show me perhaps how to use a loop and cursor to cycle through smaller date windows? The events always happen +- 24 hours.. Then I could pull let's say 3 months of data, but the window only looking within +- 24 hours? I'm not sure if maybe there's even a way to do this without PL/SQL.

EDIT: I'm now thinking maybe I could query the e2.dt and then somehow do a join or a subquery to run the logic for the +-24 hour time frame? Still not quite show how to put it all together.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
select
  ce.DT
  ,ce.SYSTEM_NO,  ce.EVENT_ID, ce.CALL_START, ce.CALL_CLEAR

  ,case when ce.event_RESTORED  between ce.call_start and 
  ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 then ce.event_RESTORED end event_RESTORED
  ,case when ce.call_GOODCALL  between ce.call_start and 
  ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 then ce.call_GOODCALL end call_GOODCALL
  ,case when ce.call_clear is not null and (ce.event_RESTORED not between 
  ce.call_start and ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 or ce.event_RESTORED is 
  null) and ce.call_GOODCALL between ce.call_start and 
  ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 then 'Y' ELSE 'N' end  call_CONNECTED

 from

 (SELECT system_no,
     dt as dt,
     e2.event_id,
       min(
     case when   e2.event_id in ('XXX001') 
       THEN e2.dt
       END
     ) OVER (
      partition by e2.system_no, case when e2.event_no is not null then to_char(e2.event_no) when  INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') <> 0 then SUBSTR(e2.commnt, INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') + 7) else to_char(e2.callid) end
     ) AS call_start,
    min(
     case when   e2.event_id in ('XXXCC') 
       THEN e2.dt
       END
     ) OVER (
      partition by   e2.system_no, case when e2.event_no is not null then to_char(e2.event_no) when  INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') <> 0 then SUBSTR(e2.commnt, INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') + 7) else to_char(e2.callid) end
     ) AS call_clear
     , min(
     case when   e2.event_id in ('XXXRE') 
       THEN e2.dt
       END
     ) OVER (
       partition by e2.system_no
      order by e2.DT
     RANGE BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING 
     ) AS event_restored
         , min(
     case when    e2.event_id in ('XXX003','XXX004') 
       THEN e2.dt
       END
     ) OVER (
       partition by e2.system_no
      order by e2.DT
     RANGE BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING 
     ) AS call_goodcall
     from CALLEVENTS e2
where 
  e2.dt >= '1-MAR-2018') ce
--e2.dt >= '1-JUN-2018') ce

where  call_clear is not null;
```

Comment: What's the selectivity of `call_clear is not null` and `e2.dt >= '1-MAR-2018'`? That is how many rows are you reading? If you are reading 100k or more, this is going to be slow.

Comment: To be honest this query is pretty simple. There's a lot of data massaging, but not real "meat" in terms of filtering, joining, or grouping. Please include the indexes you have.

Comment: Just trying to think outside the box, could creating a materialized view or temp table with just the 24 hours worth of data be an option?

Comment: @theimpaler my dbas are pretty bad about indexes, almost nothing has an index. I can however maybe create a create table as and create my own indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start adding the index:

```
create index ix1 on CALLEVENTS (dt, system_no, event_no,
  commnt, callid, event_id);
```

This index will produce an **Index Range Scan**. Hopefully it could even produce a **Index Only Scan**, that's even faster.

Please try it out and let me know how it works. If it's still slow, please post the execution plan of this query.

Comment: How do I post plans to stackoverflow? I see them in other posts in nice tables but don't know how to make them?

Comment: You get the plan by running `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT ...`. Then you edit your question and add the result of the previous SQL into it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a table on my own personal schema and adding indexes on dt, system_no, and event_no ... I also did an inner join on the same table with the condition e3.dt2 between e.dt-1 and e.dt+1 .. this query now runs in about 1 hour.. for >= 1-MAR-2018.. but if anyone has any improvments that could speed this up it would be wonderful! or just good code/format advice.. because I know... mine is very... sloppy.

```
select
ce.DT
,ce.SYSTEM_NO,  ce.EVENT_ID, ce.CALL_START, ce.CALL_CLEAR

,case when ce.event_RESTORED  between ce.call_start and 
ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 then ce.event_RESTORED end event_RESTORED
,case when ce.call_GOODCALL  between ce.call_start and 
ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 then ce.call_GOODCALL end call_GOODCALL
,case when ce.call_clear is not null and (ce.event_RESTORED not between 
ce.call_start and ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 or ce.event_RESTORED is 
null) and ce.call_GOODCALL between ce.call_start and 
ce.call_clear+0.0034722222222222 then 'Y' ELSE 'N' end  call_CONNECTED


from

(SELECT system_no,
     dt as dt,
     e.event_id,
     e3.*



  from CALLEVENTS e

  inner join (select
  system_no,
 dt as dt,
 e2.event_id,
   min(
 case when   e2.event_id in ('XXX001') 
   THEN e2.dt
   END
 ) OVER (
  partition by e2.system_no, case when e2.event_no is not null then to_char(e2.event_no) when  INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') <> 0 then SUBSTR(e2.commnt, INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') + 7) else to_char(e2.callid) end
 ) AS call_start,
min(
 case when   e2.event_id in ('XXXCC') 
   THEN e2.dt
   END
 ) OVER (
  partition by   e2.system_no, case when e2.event_no is not null then to_char(e2.event_no) when  INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') <> 0 then SUBSTR(e2.commnt, INSTR(e2.commnt, 'callid:') + 7) else to_char(e2.callid) end
 ) AS call_clear
 , min(
 case when   e2.event_id in ('XXXRE') 
   THEN e2.dt
   END
 ) OVER (
   partition by e2.system_no
  order by e2.DT
 RANGE BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING 
 ) AS event_restored
     , min(
 case when    e2.event_id in ('XXX003','XXX004') 
   THEN e2.dt
   END
 ) OVER (
   partition by e2.system_no
  order by e2.DT
 RANGE BETWEEN 0 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING 
 ) AS call_goodcall



     from CALLEVENTS e2


 ) e3 on e3.sys = e.system_no and e3.seq = e.event_no and e3.dt2 between 
 e.dt-1 and e.dt+1

 where 

 e.dt >= '1-MAR-2018') se




 where  call_clear is not null
```